# Access data type number,but populated as Text

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have an access database and excel workbook.I am using userform to pick details in the workbook to submit into the database.

There is one field (Staff Name),in the access database which its data type is set to number thus the excel userform will have mismatch error when submitting the details

My question is,why string text data type set as number.

Comment: So your colleagues are named by numbers? Not even the armed forces uses this anymore. Or so I thought. Or perhaps Excel is the clever guy here?

Comment: You would have to ask the person who has created, or last modified, this field...

Comment: When I enter data directly into the database,there is drop down list in the staffname column .but when I check from design view,the column data type is set as number

Comment: The field in question is a "Lookup field". The actual names reside in a different table and the field just contains the numeric ID of the corresponding record in that other table. Do a web search for "Access lookup field" to get more information.

Comment: I keep looking for "Access data validation" thinking it is similar to that of excel.Thanks Mr Thompson for the tips

Comment: @GordThompson nailed it. The good advice is to get rid of these fields; however smart they may seem, they will cause you nothing but trouble - as this example demonstrates.